# Symfony 2 OneToMany performance optimisation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I found a performance problem on my website.
I have an entity "Cart" with a oneToMany relation. When I call the getter method in a view that gives about 2000 queries. Then the performance of page decreases very strongly.

My entity Cart with OneTMany assoc :

```
class Cart {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comiti\UserBundle\Entity\Subscription", mappedBy="cart")
     */
    protected $subscriptions;
}
```

My entity Subscription with ManyToOne assoc :

```
class Subscription {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Comiti\UserBundle\Entity\Cart",inversedBy="subscriptions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cart_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @JMS\Exclude()
     */
    protected $cart;
}
```

My twig view with call of getSubscriptions() producing a lot of database requests :

```
{% for subscription in cart.subscriptions %}
```

What can I do to get better performances on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is called the N+1 problem. You're fetching an entity which has an association that you then traverse and query again. In your concrete example, this occurs in this loop, assuming that your subscriptions have a cost:

```
{% for subscription in cart.subscriptions %}
    {{ subscription.cost }}
```

Given that you've queried for a cart, you haven't loaded all its subscriptions and its attributes, and that's happening at loop time. To get around this, you should do a [fetch join](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) on your cart with subscriptions:

```
// in CartRepository
public function findCartWithSubscriptions($cartId)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
    $qb->leftJoin('c.subscriptions', 's')
    ->where("c = :cart")
    ->setParameter("cart", $cartId);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

This will hydrate for you a Cart object with its subscriptions loaded in memory.